# How to get an official QR code for a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook

Normally, the QR code for a Facebook page should be under Publishing Tools. However, I cannot find it under the Publishing Tools. Although I can generate one using QR code generator, the QR code from the generator directs to browser instead of Facebook app. Could I please know how to get an official QR code for my page?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying different QR Codes for my team as well and I would recommend that the best QR Code generator with logo is [QRTiger](https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/). It also fits the requirements you're looking for.